# how can i add a column to ddply output in r?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a df and all i want to do is to calculate mean, sd and sem. I have used the specificed columns for the calculation and i have used ddply for the same. It worked good but my question is how can i include one column "day" to the new df after doing ddply

Here is my df:

```
sample           side time day  value
HA2015_E1AF.bam    E    1   F  25.90898
HA2015_E1AS.bam    E    1   S  24.83408
HA2015_E1BF.bam    E    1   F  25.99592
HA2015_E2AF.bam    E    2   F  24.62888
HA2015_E2AS.bam    E    2   S  25.12230
HA2015_E2BF.bam    E    2   F  26.18967
HA2015_E3AF.bam    E    3   F  25.21953
HA2015_E3AS.bam    E    3   S  24.84422
HA2015_E3BF.bam    E    3   F  24.14083
```

Here is my ddply code and it output:

```
ddply(df, .(time, side), summarise,
               N    = length(value),
               mean = mean(value),
               sd   = sd(value),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N)
)
```

Here is my output:

```
   time side N     mean        sd        se
     1    E 6 25.46478 0.5802075 0.2368687
     2    E 6 24.95559 0.7673099 0.3132530
     3    E 6 24.34744 0.5870640 0.2396679
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. There are multiple values of  `day` for each combination of  `time` and `side` in your data. Which `day` value do you want?

Comment: May be i am thinking wrong here. Basically i want to plot the ddply result using ggplot and when i plot i would like to facet the plot by `day`. May be i cannot do it here since i am calculating the mean for the combination of `side` and `value`. Am i right?

Comment: You've calculated summary values _across different days_. `day` has completely disappeared from your data. You can certainly plot the data by `day`, but if that's what you want to do, the summarisation you've done makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Yes i realized that after comment. Thanks anyway